# Why was the edited question about tax brackets not reopened?

Tags: discussion

I am surprised that [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/101575/how-do-tax-brackets-work-do-they-yield-significantly-different-results-than-a-c) was not reopened.  (How do Tax Brackets Work; Do they Yield Significantly Different Results than a Continuous Curve?)

The question was edited so it was no longer a political question, and although every question here has an economics component, this is not principally an economics question, but a question about how a different method of graduating income taxes would affect taxpayers.

I am a newcomer to this site, and do not yet understand your tribal mores, and would appreciate an explanation of why this Q is not on topic.  If, for example, the Q had asked if there was any evidence of how the steps in tax rate affected taxpayer behavior (e.g., is there a tendency to pass on working longer hours if it puts you into a higher bracket), would such a Q be on topic?

Comment: At the moment it has 3 reopen votes (including mine) and 2 delete votes. It needs a couple of more reopen votes, or moderator intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ab2, some members have been vocal about Mods taking certain actions too quickly, and asking us to let the votes decide on certain matters. "Deleting" was a recent discussion here at Meta. In response, I agreed that reopening would happen more often if a closed question were well edited to help make it on topic. I see this one was edited, and was giving it just a bit more time to allow member to complete the process, and not have a mod stamp on it. It takes a 3K+ rep to vote to reopen, so just about 130 members have that privilege. You can see it should be in the [Review Queue](https://money.stackexchange.com/review) but only at that rep level.

TL:DR - It will be reopened soon.

Edit - The question has been reopened.